# how can i use neo4j with php on windows?

Tags: php, neo4j

i know this topic is Repetitious but I cant do it...
ir run this in my cmd

C:\Users\Asus> composer require graphaware/neo4j-php-client

and i use this code:

```
   <?php
/**
 * To install Neo4j-PHP-Client, we use Composer
 *
 * $ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
 * $ php composer.phar require graphaware/neo4j-php-client
 *
 */

require 'C:\Users\Asus\vendor\autoload.php';

use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder;

// change to your hostname, port, username, password
$neo4j_url = "neo4j@bolt://localhost:11004";

// setup connection
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->addConnection('default', $neo4j_url)
    ->build();

// setup data
$insert_query = <<<EOQ
UNWIND {pairs} as pair
MERGE (p1:Person {name:pair[0]})
MERGE (p2:Person {name:pair[1]})
MERGE (p1)-[:KNOWS]-(p2);
EOQ;

// friend data to insert
$data = [["Jim","Mike"],["Jim","Billy"],["Anna","Jim"],
    ["Anna","Mike"],["Sally","Anna"],["Joe","Sally"],
    ["Joe","Bob"],["Bob","Sally"]];

// insert data
$client->run($insert_query, ["pairs" => $data]);


// friend of friend: query
$foaf_query = <<<EOQ
MATCH (person:Person)-[:KNOWS]-(friend)-[:KNOWS]-(foaf)
WHERE person.name = {name}
  AND NOT (person)-[:KNOWS]-(foaf)
RETURN foaf.name AS name
EOQ;

// friend of friend: build and execute query
$params = ['name' => 'Joe'];
$result = $client->run($foaf_query, $params);

foreach ($result->records() as $record) {
    echo $record->get('name') . PHP_EOL;
}


// common friends: query
$common_friends_query = <<<EOQ
MATCH (user:Person)-[:KNOWS]-(friend)-[:KNOWS]-(foaf:Person)
WHERE user.name = {user} AND foaf.name = {foaf}
RETURN friend.name AS friend
EOQ;

// common friends: build and execute query
$params = ['user' => 'Joe', 'foaf' => 'Sally'];
$result = $client->run($common_friends_query, $params);

foreach ($result->records() as $record) {
    echo $record->get('friend') . PHP_EOL;
}


// connecting paths: query
$connecting_paths_query = <<<EOQ
MATCH path = shortestPath((p1:Person)-[:KNOWS*..6]-(p2:Person))
WHERE p1.name = {name1} AND p2.name = {name2}
RETURN [n IN nodes(path) | n.name] as names
EOQ;

// connecting paths: build and execute query
$params = ['name1' => 'Joe', 'name2' => 'Billy'];
$result = $client->run($connecting_paths_query, $params);

foreach ($result->records() as $record) {
    print_r($record->get('names'));
}
```

and i have this error 
Notice: Undefined index: scheme in C:\Users\Asus\vendor\graphaware\neo4j-php-client\src\Connection\Connection.php on line 77

Notice: Undefined index: host in C:\Users\Asus\vendor\graphaware\neo4j-php-client\src\Connection\Connection.php on line 77

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://://:7687:7687 (The requested address is not valid in its context. ) in C:\Users\Asus\vendor\graphaware\neo4j-bolt\src\IO\StreamSocket.php on line 167

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GraphAware\Bolt\Exception\IOException' with message 'Error to connect to the server(10049) : "The requested address is not valid in its context. "' in C:\Users\Asus\vendor\graphaware\neo4j-bolt\src\IO\StreamSocket.php:170 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\Asus\vendor\graphaware\neo4j-bolt\src\IO\StreamSocket.php(189): GraphAware\Bolt\IO\StreamSocket->connect() #1 C:\Users\Asus\vendor\graphaware\neo4j-bolt\src\Driver.php(114): GraphAware\Bolt\IO\StreamSocket->reconnect() #2 C:\Users\Asus\vendor\graphaware\neo4j-bolt\src\Driver.php(98): GraphAware\Bolt\Driver->handshake() #3 C:\Users\Asus\vendor\graphaware\neo4j-php-client\src\Connection\Connection.php(164): GraphAware\Bolt\Driver->session() #4 C:\Users\Asus\vendor\graphaware\neo4j-php-client\src\Connection\Connection.php(115): GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection->checkSession() #5 C:\Users\Asus\vendor\graphaware\neo4j-php-client\src\Client.php(45): GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection->run('UNWIND {pairs} ...', Array, NULL) #6 C in C:\Users\Asus\vendor\graphaware\neo4j-bolt\src\IO\StreamSocket.php on line 170

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace looks like it cannot parse the connection URL, because it looks like it is coming up with no *scheme* and no *host*.

It looks to me like it traces back to this line in the code you posted:

```
$client->run($insert_query, ["pairs" => $data]);
```

which I think is ultimately using the URL defined on this line:

```
$neo4j_url = "neo4j@bolt://localhost:11004";
```

but that format looks wrong to me; when username and password are provided as part of a URL, the format is:

```
 foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
 \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
  |           |            |            |        |
scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
```

and the `authority` portion is:

```
authority   = [ userinfo "@" ] host [ ":" port ]
```

So the URL I think you want is :

```
$neo4j_url = "http://neo4j:bolt@localhost:11004/";      -or-
$neo4j_url = "bolt://neo4j:password@localhost:11004/";  <-- from doc linked in comment
```

Some of this is guesswork, but I hope this solves it, or sets you on the right path to solving it.

Reference for the format of a URI : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

Comment: Correct, also specifying `neo4j` is useless as this is the default user. Secondly, the examples in the README are pretty clear https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client#installation

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen  a very pertinent link; thanks!  now I see that `bolt` is a scheme that is applicable here; that resolves some of my guesswork; I will edit my answer accordingly